# Hibernate Error with openjdk : unable to make field private final java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am trying to put hibernate into a jee project with Eclipse. I have installed the hibernate tools and i have an error which appears when i try to create an hibernate console configuration:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.ArrayList jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.loaders accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @76783608
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:337)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:281)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:176)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:170)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfigClassLoader.closeClassLoader(ConsoleConfigClassLoader.java:190)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfigClassLoader.close(ConsoleConfigClassLoader.java:43)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.cleanUpClassLoader(ConsoleConfiguration.java:163)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.reinitClassLoader(ConsoleConfiguration.java:182)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.buildWith(ConsoleConfiguration.java:238)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:123)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:64)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:232)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

It seems to come from the Open JDK and i would like to know how i could solve it.

Thanks you for your help.

Vinz

Comment: Do you have solved this? I have the same error also if I use jdk 7 or 8 with eclipse oxygen. Thank you.

Comment: @Tudor no, i didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

In a very strange manner, I have solved it!

Simply try to delete in your environment any JDK (9+) that you not use and reinstall hibernate tools with JDK <= 8.